# Struct reuse for Modules in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What mechanisms are there to achieve struct reuse: define a struct with all the fields of another struct plus some of its own.

I have these structs that sort of look like this

```
defmodule VideoView do
  defstruct name: nil, description: nil, video_link: nil, ...
end

defmodule ImagesView do
  defstruct name: nil, description: nil, images: [], ...
end

defmodule Model3DView do
  defstruct name: nil, description: nil, model: nil, ...
end
```

There are 7 of these. In my UML they all inherit from `View` which has `name` and `description`. I'd like all of them to share these common fields, especially if I decide to add or remove a common field, this could be a real pain with the current method.

Comment: If your main question is point 1 (as you said in the comments below) then you should edit your question.  And, by the way, it would help a lot to make a good recommendation to you if you would specify the use case you're trying to tackle.  There's not any generic way (at least as far as I know) in Elixir to reuse structs so it would help to know _why_ you want to reuse them.

Comment: Changed the question. Sometimes I don't like to be specific about my problem so the answers are general, but I guess I lacked some illustration here.

Answer (score 11):

As others have suggested, you should really think twice whether you really gain that much from re-using structs.

If you still need it to reduce massive duplication, you can use module attributes to initially store the struct options. Then you can re-use them with `defstruct` and expose them for other modules through a function:

```
defmodule View do
  @common_fields [name: nil, description: nil]
  def common_fields, do: @common_fields
  defstruct @common_fields
end
```

If you do not plan on using `View` on its own, you can just put the common fields in a function directly:

```
defmodule View do
  def common_fields do
    [name: nil, description: nil]
  end
end
```

Then, you can use the common fields in your other structs like this:

```
defmodule VideoView do
  defstruct View.common_fields ++ [video_link: nil, ...]
end

defmodule ImagesView do
  defstruct View.common_fields ++ [images: [], ...]
end

defmodule Model3DView do
  defstruct View.common_fields ++ [model: nil, ...]
end
```

Comment: My real worry is #1, I don't know if I need to change the question to focus on that.

Comment: @CristianGarcia thanks for the edit. I edited my entire answer again to reflect your edited question. Good point about the macro, I was initially trying something more complicated.

Comment: That's a good solution Patrick. I still think he needs to free himself of the idea that everything must be an object but you've presented a practical, simple solution.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci You are right, this is a great answer and was probably implied by one of the "he needs to let go of oop" and "he needs to think in terms of fp" comments which are far more abundant than actual answers. This kind of behaviour was somehow allowed to sink into the community and as a beginner I find it hard to extract actual information from those.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no straightforward way to do 1. If you mess around enough with macros, you can probably figure one out. A struct in Elixir is actually a function with zero arguments `__struct__/0`, that returns a map
with default values.

You can import another module's functions into your module and it is possible to override a function defined in the other module with your own definition if the 
function in the other module is defined as overrideable.

```
use OtherModule
```

But you cannot export those functions, you can only export functions defined
in the module.

If you want inheritance Elixir is not the language you want to use. Instead of inheritance, Elixir focuses on composition of functions and transformation of data. Bringing a lot of baggage from the OO world will only slow you down.

In this case, if you need a data structure from another module you should think composition rather than inheritance. One way to do this would be

```
defstruct other_module: struct(Other_Module), foo: nil , bar: 1
```

For the most part Elixir is an expression based language, you can almost always exchange a data value for a runtime function call and vice versa.

Comment: I hear that a lot but nobody gives a practical example, or a blog post on how to deal with the real issue that it code reuse.

Comment: My real worry is how guarantee that the struct of every module gets certain common fields for free so the code is maintainable.

Comment: Change the words, my intention is not to get OO into Elixir, I just have some use cases I need to solve.

Comment: Use Maps not Structs. A struct is just a convience for getting a "standard" map that works with the functions in the module. Do not confuse coding convience with program design. A struct is just a handy default map.

Comment: But structs: 1) provide type information useful when pattern matching, 2) define useful default values for certain fields.

Comment: Definitely agree with @FredtheMagicWonderDog; thinking in terms of OO only slows a person down when working with Elixir.

Answer (score 2):

1. Struct reuse:

a. First consider do you really need to reuse the struct. It sounds as if you're considering a struct as a form of an object. It's not that.

b. It would help to recommend a course of action if we had a better idea of your use case.

2. Function reuse:

a. You're thinking of it wrong.  In OO different behavior is achieved via inheritance and overriding functions in the derived class.  In FP there's no need for that because you can simply pass in the new functionality as a parameter to the function.

Consider the following sample code:

```
defmodule FReuseExample do
   def func1 do
      IO.puts "func1"
   end

   def func2 do
      IO.puts "func2"
   end

   def my_varying_func(f) do
      f.()
   end
end
```

Then I would call it in this way:

```
FReuseExample.my_varying_func(&FReuseExample.func1/0)
```

Or if I needed the behavior specified in `func2` then I'd do this:

```
FReuseExample.my_varying_func(&FReuseExample.func2/0)
```

The point is that I don't need an inheritance hierarchy.  I can simply pass the behavior that I need as a parameter to the function.  The original intent of inheritance was to modify behavior according to the more specific type which was being used.  If I can pass in behavior directly I no longer need inheritance to get this.

Comment: I think you are fighting OO to much to see the the problem: if you need many structs that share certain fields you need to manually write them ever time on each struct. Also, most languages including C# have higher order functions, but the correct solution in Elixir would be protocols or import.

Comment: Have you tried to use higher order functions in C# @CristianGarcia?  It's extremely clumsy. People had common data long before OO came along; you're just used to thinking in terms of inheritance.  There's nothing any more of less intuitive about inheritance for common data structures than using modules of functions which all access the same data structure.